# FQL with Client access_token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, oauth-2.0

Can you run FQL with a client access_token? I want to do something like:

`SELECT user_online_presence FROM user WHERE uid IN ([UID1],[UID2],[UID3],...)`

Where I have the user_online_presence permission for each of my users.

Is this documented anywhere?  I only found out about the client token in the real-time updates documentation, but then this thread shows I completely different implementation:
[Facebook real-time user updates](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4062246/facebook-real-time-user-updates)

Does the client access_token eliminate the need to extend my user_access token?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that this isn't documented should warn you that its behaviour can change at any time, so please do not rely upon it. However, currently, an app access token *can* be used to retrieve most of the fields and connections for a user when that user has already granted the same app permission to access the data and assuming the user access token has not expired.

So, for example, having requested `user_location` permission from a user and getting it will allow the app access token access to the `current_location` field for that particular user.

As I said, if it isn't documented, don't rely upon it - instead continue to use user access tokens wherever relevant.

Additionally, one correction to your FQL query above - the field is `online_presence` (whereas the permission to access that field is `user_online_presence`).